# PowerShell Filtering between pipelines

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm writing a script to archive files in folders, which works fine. But now I want to implement an extra filter called `$OlderThan` and that's where I'm struggling now.

**The script:**

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [String]$Source,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [String]$Destination = $Source,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet('Year','Year\Month','Year-Month')]
    [String]$Structure = 'Year\Month',
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet('Day','Month','Year')]
    [String]$OlderThan = 'Day',
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Int]$Quantity = '1'
)
Begin {
    $Today = Get-Date
    $When = ($Today.AddDays(-"$Quantity")).Date
}
Process {
    Get-ChildItem $Source -File | ForEach-Object {
        $File = $_
        # Get folder name
        $ChildPath = Switch ($Structure) {
            'Year'       { [String]$File.CreationTime.Year }
            'Year\Month' { [String]$File.CreationTime.Year+"\"+$File.CreationTime.ToString("MM") }
            'Year-Month' { [String]$File.CreationTime.Year+"-"+$File.CreationTime.ToString("MM") }
        }
        $Target = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $ChildPath

        # Move the file
        if (Test-Path $Target -PathType Container) { 
            Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        } 
        else {
            New-Item $Target -Type Directory | Out-Null
            Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
}
```

**The extra filter:**

```
Switch ($OlderThan) {
    'Day'    { where ($File.CreationTime -le $(($Today.AddDays(-"$Quantity")).Date))}
    'Month'  { where {$File.CreationTime.Month -lt $Today.Month }}
    'Year'   { where {$File.CreationTime.Year -lt $Today.Year }}
}
```

How can I implement this the best way? The purpose is that when `Day`, `Month` or `Year` is chosen, this filter is applied after `Get-ChildItem` based on the file's `CreationTime`. So only those files are moved that comply with the filter.

For the moment I created a workaround for this, by creating a function like below. But is it really needed to create a function just to have these 3 filters between the pipeline? It feels like I'm over complicating things.

**Current workaround:**

```
Function Select-Stuff {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        $File
    )
    Process {
        Switch ($OlderThan) {
            'Day'    { if ($File.CreationTime -le $When) {Write-Output $File} }
            'Month'  { if ($File.CreationTime.Month -lt $Today.Month) {Write-Output $File} }
            'Year'   { if ($File.CreationTime.Year -lt $Today.Year) {Write-Output $File} }
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem $Source -File | Select-Stuff | ForEach-Object {
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can off course always make a script block out of it and call it from within the `Switch`. But I would like to be able to use the pipeline if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to create that filter would be to (literally) create that filter:

```
 Begin {
    $Today = Get-Date
    $When = ($Today.AddDays(-"$Quantity")).Date

    Switch ($OlderThan) {
    'Day'    { filter Get-OlderThan  { if ($_.CreationTime -le $(($Today.AddDays(-"$Quantity").Date))) {$_} } }
    'Month'  { filter Get-OlderThan { if ( $_.CreationTime.Month -lt $Today.Month) {$_} } }
    'Year'   { filter Get-OlderThan { if ($_.CreationTime.Year -lt $Today.Year) {$_} } }
    Default  { filter Get-OlderThan {$_ } }
  }
}
Process {
    Get-ChildItem $Source -File | 
    Get-OlderThan | ForEach-Object {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, awesome, awesome! I didn't know about the existence of `Filter` in PowerShell. And writing a function specifically for this with parameters and everything seemed like overkill. Thank you very much mjolinor, appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome! Filters are basically just a function that implicitly have only a Process block.  You don't see them used much, but they can be handy things on occasion :)

Comment: I fully agree! They make things a lot cleaner/easier to read when it's only about `filtering` stuff :)